# Given the Following List (UL), how can it be serialized and sent to the Database

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the follow structure which is created with a nested sortable:

```
<UL id="container">
    <LI id="main1">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        <UL>
            <LI id="child2">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
                <UL></UL>
            </LI>
        </UL>
    </LI>
    <LI id="main3">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
        <UL></UL>
    </LI>
    <LI id="main4">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
        <UL></UL>
    </LI>
    <LI id="main5">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
        <UL></UL>
    </LI>
</UL>
```

Where I'm stuck is how to send this back to the database. I'm guessing that it needs to be serialized, does that sound right too? I'm open to suggestions on how to best store the ordering in the database in a way that has each list item as it's on record.

What can I try next?

Comment: Your suggested output is confusing (I'm assuming its to be part of a urlstring; i could be mistaken). Is this what you mean: checkbox1=value&checkbox2=othervalue&... and so on?

Comment: I don't a set format really, just a way to store the positions in database so I can display the list in the future. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your server side language?

Comment: I found this plugin which actually works.. But What do I do with this data on the backend? http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/01/jquery_serialize_list_plugin/

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your lists in a `form` element and then give all of your checkboxes `name` attributes, you can use the jQuery `$.serialize` method:

```
$.post('/url/to/send/', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(){//callback});
```

Comment: Jason, thxs, I don't want to send back the checkbox info.

I just want to send back the order. something like: 

ul[0][id]=main1

ul[0][children][0][id]=child2

ul[0][children][1][id]=main3

ul[0][children][2][id]=main4

ul[1][id]=main5

Comment: well that sounds like something a bit more complex. maybe you could include some named hidden inputs next to the checkboxes (don't give the checkboxes names) with a value as to what their order is. then serialize the form and send it off.

Comment: I'm not interested in the checkboxes at all just the lists order and having a way to save that in the db. Make sense?

Comment: right, i get it. what i'm telling you is to put hidden inputs: `<input type="hidden" name="ul0" id="ul0" value="main1">` etc. then serialize your form and you will get something like `{"ul0":"main1", etc}`. it's not pretty, but it will work.

Comment: I'm not at the point of frustration where I can't to slap something together :) there has to be a clean, right way here.

Comment: unfortunately there doesn't have to be. this isn't a typical necessity. good luck

Answer (score -1):

If the question is literally "how can I display this list in the future?" (i.e. this exact same html) I'd suggest a templating engine (choices will depend on your server-side language).
Now if the question if "how do I get the values of the checkboxes into the appropriate database fields?" then you'll probably want to use jquery's `:checkbox` css selector syntax to get all the checkboxes and then get their values from that. Or you could throw form tags around the whole thing and do a bunch of processing server-side (not pretty).

EDIT: After looking at your comments on Jason's answer, it occurs to me that you could select all the checkboxes and all the `<ul>`'s of a particular `<ul>`. Obviously, you'll need to do this recursively, but it should give you something (an array of some kind) that you can recreate the tree from.